# Почему не работает попап на скопированной странице (elementor)?

Tags: wordpress, всплывающее-окно, elementor

Есть страница с попапом сделанная в элементоре. Я сделал копию этой страницы, но там попап не работает. В оригинальной странице присутствует html-код попапа, а в копии его нет. Обе страницы абсолютно одинаковые, но в копии нет попапа. Я пробовал сохранить шаблон оригинальной страницы и сделать новую на его основе, но результат то же. Почему не работает попап?